# Filter a table using information in cells outside of the table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that pulls in information from multiple different sources throughout my workbook. There are 4 categories that the table will be filtered on regularly and used by users that are not strong in excel.

I would like to set up a filtering section with lists that filter the table below. The screenshot shows the proposed setup with list values being in cells `B4`,`C4`,`D4`,`E4` and the table below being what would be filtered based on the values that are input.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this or something similar?

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Can't find Column for VP in the Screen Shot also, Region and Market  columns has have single value so useless to include as Filter Criteria the best possible are Building and Market, use as Criteria. *Confirm through comments whether this will work for you or not, then I'll show you how to achieve it !*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean that you want to filter by a specific cell value, rather than filtering with the built in table filtering?

Well, you can call on the autofilter with a macro, and use the value of the cells as criterias.

You can put the macro in the sheet, and have it called automatically each time one of the relevant cells are changed with a `Worksheet_Change` sub.

There are a lot of ways to write this, but we need to specify what table we want to filter, and we also need to specify which row to filter.

This is the code i put in the sheet (by right clicking the sheet tab and select "show code") for my example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim tabl As String, i As Long, C as Range
tabl = "Table1" 'Name of the Table
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("B4:E4")) Is Nothing And Target.Count < 5 Then
    For Each C In Target
        tCol = Range(tabl & "[" & C.Offset(-1).Value2 & "]").Column
        If C.Value2 = "" Then
            ListObjects(tabl).Range.AutoFilter Field:=tCol
        Else
            ListObjects(tabl).Range.AutoFilter Field:=tCol, Criteria1:=C.Value2
        End If
    Next C
End If
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

*Edit*
Added loop to be able to clear all filters at once.

This Code requires your Headers to be the same over the input cell and in the Table, or it will throw an error.

-

`Worksheet_Change` is called when cells on the worksheet are changed.
This is often used in conjunction with
`If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("")) Is Nothing Then`
to restrict the sub from running unless specific areas are targeted.

Having a restriction on `Target.Count` is also a good idea, to keep the code from crashing. Often you want to restrict it to a single target, unless you intend to loop the selection, like I did in this case.

If you like to have drop down lists with the options, there's a a VBA approach here: [excel-removing-duplicates-with-data-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749526/excel-removing-duplicates-with-data-validation)

Comment: This worked awesome thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**I would like to suggest an Array (CSE) Formula, will help you to extract multiple Rows based on few Criteria.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- I'm assuming that the Source Data is in Range 
  `A2:E10`.
- Criteria Range is `A16:E16`.
- Enter this Formula in Cell `A20`, finish with 
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill Right then Down.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$E$10,SMALL(IF(MMULT(($A$2:$E$10=$A$16:$E$16)*1,{1;1;1;1;1;1;1})=COUNTA($A$16:$E$16),MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$10),ROW($A$2:$A$10)),""),ROWS($A$1:A1)),COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")}`

**Note:**

- If Criteria Cell/Cells will blank, this Formula 
  will return All records.

[image]

- You may put one ore more than one Criteria to Filter related Records.

[image]

**Let me explain the mechanism of the Command.**

- `MMULT function` can't work with Boolean values 
  so in order to get that working, Formula must 
  multiply the array with 1.

`MMULT(($A$2:$E$10=$A$16:$E$16)*1,{1;1;1;1;1;1;1})`

becomes,

```
MMULT({0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0;0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0;0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0;0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0;0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0;0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},{1;1;1;1;1;1;1})
```

and returns,

```
{0;0;1;0;0;2;1;1;2;1}
```

and,

```
MMULT(($A$2:$E$10=$A$16:$E$16)*1, {1;1;1;1;1;1;1})=COUNTA($A$16:$E$16)
```

becomes,

```
{0;0;1;0;0;2;1;1;2;1}=COUNTA($A$16:$E$16)
```

becomes,

```
{0;0;1;0;0;2;1;1;2;1}=2
```

and returns,

```
{FALSE; FALSE; FALSE; FALSE; FALSE; TRUE; FALSE; FALSE; TRUE; FALSE}.

IF(MMULT(($A$2:$E$10=$A$16:$E$16)*1, {1;1;1;1;1;1;1})=COUNTA($A$16:$E$16), MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$10), ROW($A$2:$A$10)), "")
```

becomes,

```
IF({FALSE; FALSE; FALSE; FALSE; FALSE; TRUE; FALSE; FALSE; TRUE; FALSE}, MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$10), ROW($A$2:$A$10)), "")
```

- **SMALL** Function gets the k-th smallest 
  number in an Array.
- **INDEX** Function returns a value from a cell 
  Range or Array, based on a Row and Column 
  number.